# django inline admin model and generic relations

Tags: django

I've got an inline admin model with a generic foreignkey and I want to validate a set of it's properties in the models clean() method. If I add a new model neither content_type nor object_id is set in the clean() method, but if I try to change an existing model of course I can access the content_type property.

Is there any work-around to get the content_type when I first add a new model?

Any hint or url is appreciated
Thanks && have a nice day! :)

Basti

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, something like the following should work:

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel

    def clean(self):
        content_type = self.cleaned_data.get('content_type')
        object_id = self.cleaned_data.get('object_id')

        if content_type and object_id:
            obj = content_type.get_object_for_this_type(pk=object_id)
            # Check whatever on the object here, and if there's a problem:
            # raise forms.ValidationError('Something is not right')

        return self.cleaned_data
```